# Magento OnePageCheckout Redirect After "Place Order" Click

Tags: magento, redirect

can anyone help with the following issue.

Once a customer in onepagecheckout clicks the „order now“ button I would like to show a custom page for 2-3seconds and the forward to either payment provider or thankyou page.

Currently I have an observer on 
"checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after"
calling my custom model/method.

In this model/method I do a...

```
$this->_forward($url); //with $url being a custom controller/method
$res->sendResponse();
exit;
```

In this custom controller/method I load and render my layout the show my *.phtml – file and then...

```
$url = Mage::getUrl("???");
$this->_forward($url);<
$res = Mage::app()->getResponse();
$res->sendResponse();
```

And this is where I am lost (or maybe I am totally wrong on the whole thing). 
First of all, the controller does not forward at all (whatever url or controller is given). 
Second how do I know where to redirect to (if its payment provider or thank you page)

Is there a better way to „simply“ load a *.phtml after user clicks „order now“ and before he is redirected to either thank-you-page or payment-provider.

The phtml is user to load tracking code which must be placed and loaded in html.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest instead that you consider doing the following:

- Adding a javascript action to the place order button in the order review which will effectively issue an in-screen modal or popup
- The click issuing the modal will set a timeout of 3000ms (3 seconds) which will then fire the order submit Ajax that Magento uses. This is important as the order submit and the redirect are dependent on AJAX.

This example jQuery script (requires adding jQuery to your Magento site, which is not standard) would set the timeout, issue the modal / popup I would add this code to the following file:

`/app/design/frontend/[your theme]/template/checkout/onepage/review/button.phtml`

Add a class to this line and remove the onclick event so you can capture the click and interject your timeout:

```
<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?>" class="btn-place-order button btn-checkout"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?></span></span></button>

<script>
    $('#myform').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //issue the popup - put your html in here:
        var html = '<div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; min-height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color:white;"><h1>I am a popup</h1></div>';
        $('body').append(html);
        var self = this;
        window.setTimeout(function() {
        review.save();
        }, 3000);
    });
</script>
```